# Error: Action Required, This is the error that i am getting in service side lightning program

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

Error

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Action
> failed: c:LC_1103_Eg4_SumUpEven$controller$calc [ation is not defined]
> Failing descriptor: {c:LC_1103_Eg4_SumUpEven$controller$calc}

Class

```
public class LC_1103_Eg4_SumUpEven {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Integer sumuptoeven(integer numb)
    {
      integer Res=1;
      integer count=0;
        while(count<numb){
            Res=Res+count;
            count=count+2;
        }
        Return Res;
    }

}
```

component

```
<aura:component controller="LC_1103_Eg4_SumUpEven">
    <aura:attribute name="num" type="Integer"/>
    <aura:attribute name="Result" type="Integer"/>
    
    <lightning:card title="SUM">
        <lightning:input label="Enter the Number" value="{!v.num}"/>
        <lightning:button label="Calulate" onclick="{!c.calc}"/><br/>
        <lightning:input label="Result" value="{!v.Result}"/>
         
    </lightning:card>
    
</aura:component>
```

controller

```
({
    calc : function(component, event, helper) {
        var n=component.get("v.num");
         var action=component.get("c.sumuptoeven");
        action.setParams({"numb":n});
        ation.setCallback(this,function(response){
              var state=response.getState();
                if(state=='SUCCESS')
                {
                    var res=response.getReturnValue();
                    component.set("v.result",res);
                }                  
          });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Application

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <c:LC_1103_Eg4_SumUpEven/>
</aura:application>
```

Comment: Please use the format tool `{ }` to properly format the code and add details about the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

You have a very small problem, you have misspelled the `action` variable. Please check the below code.

```
({
    calc : function(component, event, helper) {
        var n=component.get("v.num");
         var action=component.get("c.sumuptoeven");
        action.setParams({"numb":n});
        action.setCallback(this,function(response){
              var state=response.getState();
                if(state=='SUCCESS')
                {
                    var res=response.getReturnValue();
                    component.set("v.result",res);
                }                  
          });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Comment: Tq..Rahul. The Error gone now.

Comment: But The problem is Result is not getting displayed on the output paga

Comment: @Mahi JavaScript is cAsE-sEnSiTiVe. You named the attribute Result, but assigned to attribute result.